# Why do returned data rows from Google Analytics Reporting API include zero values for metrics?

Tags: google-analytics-api, google-reporting-api

I use the Google Analytics (GA) Reporting API to retrieve custom data from my GA views. Often my queries include a mixture of standard and custom dimensions regarding different URLs and their respective page views, e.g. something like ga:pagePath, ga:pageTitle, ga:dimensionX, where dimensionX is set on a hit level and send with every page view (like publishing date or some CMS identifier).

The returned data regularly includes rows that represent some kind of dimension combination with 0 page views. How can that be? Why would GA report a data point with 0 hits?

PS: I don't use 360, so sampling applies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have set `includeEmptyRows: true` in the request.

> includeEmptyRows   boolean
>
> If set to false, the response does not include rows if all the
>   retrieved metrics are equal to zero. The default is false which will
>   exclude these rows.

from: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet#ReportRequest

Comment: I don't specify `includeEmptyRows` in my queries at all, but it defaults to true vor API version 3: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#includeEmptyRows. So, this might be the culprit